# What's the difference between "Restorations" and "Resubscribing" in android subscription?

Tags: android, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription, play-billing-library, google-play-billing

I'm implementing Android new subscription feature in my application.
I have checked the [docs](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/subs). But I don't understand the difference between [Restorations](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/subs#restore) and [Resubscribing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/subs#resubscribe) before the subscription has expired.
How do users benefit from resubscribing?
If anyone knows more about this, please teach me.

Best Regards,